# What \u001B]0;kuba@jcubic: ~\u0007 escape code do?

Tags: bash, escape-characters

When using shell in a box this is returned from the server

```
\r\n\u001B]0;kuba@jcubic:~\u0007\u001B[01;32mkuba@jcubic\u001B[00m:\u001B[01;34m~\u001B[00m$
```

what `ESC]0;` and `\u0007` do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are [XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html), so from that list ESC ] is an "Operating System Command", and then down in that section one finds:

```
OSC Ps ; Pt BEL
  Ps = 0  -> Change Icon Name and Window Title to Pt.
```

The use of unicode (`\u...`) is a bit odd, though the low number values used here can be looked up in `man ascii`:

```
$ man ascii | egrep -i '1b|007'
       007   7     07    BEL '\a' (bell)             107   71    47    G
       033   27    1B    ESC (escape)                133   91    5B    [
```